# Reverse Pointer function issue

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm having an issue with the pointer return function. The error, "calling object type 'int* ' is not a function or a function pointer" `reverseArray = reverseArray(array,size);`.I am not sure why it's giving me this error, this is not my solution I'm using this solution as a guidance to help me solve the problem. Since I've sat for now 2 hours trying to solve it and I got no where with it, so I decide to look it up and get an idea on how to approach the problem. And break down their solution by using a debugger to see why their solution works. I know it's a bad thing to do because I'm not learning how to solve problems on my own.

```
#include <iostream>
int* reverseArray(int [], int );
int main()
{   const int size =5;
    int array[size] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    int* reverseArray;

    for(int i =0; i < size;i++)
    {
        std::cout << array[i];
    }

    reverseArray = reverseArray(array,size);

    for(int i =0; i <size;i++)
    {
        std::cout <<array[i];
    }

    return 0;
}

int* reverseArray(int array [],int size)
{

    int* newArray;
    newArray = new int[size];

    int j = 0;

    for(int k =size-1;k>=0;k--)
    {
        newArray[j] = array[k];
        j++;
    }


    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: You used the same name for a function and a variable.  The variable hides the function, so you can't easily call the function while it's in scope.

Comment: Okay, that makes thing a more clearer, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The error is self explanatory.

**"calling object type 'int* ' is not a function or a function pointer"**. In you `main()` function, you named the array you want to pass as a parameter to your `reverseArray()` function with the same name as your function (reverseArray). The compiler get confused within that scope, because of this and thinks you're calling a **variable** as a **function**.

See below:

```
#include <iostream>
int* reverseArray(int [], int );
int main()
{   const int size =5;
    int array[size] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    int* reverseArray; // Change this name to something else

    for(int i =0; i < size;i++)
    {
        std::cout << array[i];
    }

    reverseArray = reverseArray(array,size);

    for(int i =0; i <size;i++)
    {
        std::cout <<array[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm just curious. Is there a better way in writing the reverse function?

Comment: Generally in programming languages, recursion is the best way to go! You can achieve that with some effort in C++ as well. If you ask another question about it, I'll upvote it and try to show you how. Let me know @Pierre

Comment: Yes, that would be awesome!